# django template backend for Jinja2

Tags: django, templates, jinja2

is there difference between

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
        .......
    },
]
```

and (imported from django-jinja package)

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django_jinja.backend.Jinja2",
        .......
    },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not from the same package and doesn't have the same features.

From django-jinja documentation (http://niwinz.github.io/django-jinja/latest/)

> Django comes with a jinja backend, why should I use django-jinja?
>
> The Django builtin backend has a very limited set of features if we
> compare it with the django template engine and in my opinion is not
> very usable because it does not integrate well with the rest of django
> such as its filters, template tags and preloading of templatetags,
> among others.

So it is up to you to see if you need those extra feature or not.